# Does IBM DB2 support character length semantics?

Tags: db2

Does IBM DB2 support character length semantics?  If yes, then please tell me how to enable it.
Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "character length semantics".

Comment: Depends on the version and platform, either of which you chose not to disclose.

Comment: Please clarify more details. My customer want a database engine which supports character length semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation [for whatever variant\platform and version] of DB2 that is an available option [i.e. existing and\or installed, or can be obtained], for availability of the scalar function:

> CHARACTER_LENGTH
>
> The CHARACTER_LENGTH or CHAR_LENGTH function returns the length of a string expression.
>
> >>-+-CHARACTER_LENGTH-+--(--expression--)---------------------->
>       '-CHAR_LENGTH------'